# python regex not working on string encoding

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a string (g) on which I run a simple regex to find a number.  The problem is that somehow the regex doesn't work on that string type (encoding?).
A "normal" string works however.
What am I missing?  Please see below the steps as seen on the repl:

(example is a summary of an online poker tournament)

***NOT WORKING:***

```
>>> g
'F\x00u\x00l\x00l\x00 \x00T\x00i\x00l\x00t\x00 \x00P\x00o\x00k\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00T\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00S\x00u\x00m\x00m\x00a\x00r\x00y\x00 \x00$\x002\x00.\x002\x005\x00 \x00H\x00e\x00a\x00d\x00s\x00-\x00U\x00p\x00 \x00S\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00&\x00 \x00G\x00o\x00 \x00(\x002\x005\x000\x005\x005\x005\x009\x001\x004\x00)\x00 \x002\x00-\x007\x00 \x00T\x00r\x00i\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00 \x00D\x00r\x00a\x00w\x00 \x00L\x00i\x00m\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00(\x00T\x00u\x00r\x00b\x00o\x00,\x00 \x00H\x00e\x00a\x00d\x00s\x00 \x00U\x00p\x00)\x00\n\x00B\x00u\x00y\x00-\x00I\x00n\x00:\x00 \x00$\x002\x00.\x001\x002\x00 \x00+\x00 \x00$\x000\x00.\x001\x003\x00\n\x00B\x00u\x00y\x00-\x00I\x00n\x00 \x00C\x00h\x00i\x00p\x00s\x00:\x00 \x001\x005\x000\x000\x00\n\x002\x00 \x00E\x00n\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00\n\x00T\x00o\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00P\x00r\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00P\x00o\x00o\x00l\x00:\x00 \x00$\x004\x00.\x002\x004\x00\n\x00T\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00:\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x003\x00/\x000\x003\x00/\x000\x008\x00 \x000\x006\x00:\x000\x000\x00:\x002\x007\x00 \x00E\x00T\x00\n\x00T\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00f\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00s\x00h\x00e\x00d\x00:\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x003\x00/\x000\x003\x00/\x000\x008\x00 \x000\x006\x00:\x001\x004\x00:\x003\x000\x00 \x00E\x00T\x00\n\x00\n\x001\x00:\x00 \x00A\x00n\x00d\x00r\x00e\x00y\x003\x003\x001\x000\x00,\x00 \x00$\x004\x00.\x002\x004\x00\n\x002\x00:\x00 \x00s\x00y\x00n\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00s\x00i\x00i\x00s\x00\n\x00s\x00y\x00n\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00s\x00i\x00i\x00s\x00 \x00f\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00s\x00h\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x002\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00a\x00c\x00e'
>>> myre = re.compile(u"""\(([0-9]+)\)""",re.UNICODE)
>>> m = myre.search(g)
>>> m.groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

***WORKING***

```
>>> g="Full Tilt Poker Tournament Summary $2.25 Heads-Up Sit & Go (250555914) 2-7 Triple Draw Limit (Turbo, Heads Up)"
>>> m = myre.search(g)
>>> m.groups()
('250555914',)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have UTF-16 encoded data, albeit without a BOM (Byte Order Mark). Decode to Unicode first before attempting to match the regex:

```
>>> g[:-1].decode('utf-16-le')
u'Full Tilt Poker Tournament Summary $2.25 Heads-Up Sit & Go (250555914) 2-7 Triple Draw Limit (Turbo, Heads Up)\nBuy-In: $2.12 + $0.13\nBuy-In Chips: 1500\n2 Entries\nTotal Prize Pool: $4.24\nTournament started: 2013/03/08 06:00:27 ET\nTournament finished: 2013/03/08 06:14:30 ET\n\n1: Andrey3310, $4.24\n2: synthesiis\nsynthesiis finished in 2nd plac'
>>> myre.search(g[:-1].decode('utf-16-le')).groups()
(u'250555914',)
```

I had to remove the last byte to make that decode though, a null byte at the end was missing. If you are missing data from the end, you are most likely also missing the data from the *start*, where the BOM would be located. The BOM tells the decoder what variant of UTF-16 was used to encode (little or big endian), without it we need to explicitly tell Python to decode this as little endian.

If you decode the *full* data, including the BOM, you could just use `.decode('utf-16')` instead.

If you are reading this from a file, use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead and have Python decode it to Unicode for you:

```
import codecs

for line in codecs.open('filename.txt', 'r', encoding='utf16'):
    # handle line
```

because otherwise things like `.readlines()` splits newlines at the byte level, which are encoded to two bytes just like everything else in UTF-16.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters, I still don't understand why I get this format when I open(file).readlines() instead of the normal utf-16 format.  Would you be able to help with that point?

Comment: Don't use `readlines()` on a UTF-16-encoded file! Newlines are encoded as two bytes too, and you are splitting the file now. Use `codecs.open()` and read Unicode data.